# PHP handling posted array

Tags: php, arrays, post

So I have some inputs in my html formatted like this

```
<input name="First_Corp[FirstName]" />
<input name="First_Corp[LastName]" />
<input name="Second_Corp[FirstName]" />
<input name="Second_Corp[LastName]" />
```

These are posted to a php processing page as expected. So `$_POST["First_Corp"]["FirstName"]` gives the value of the right input. I am grouping them in arrays so that they can be formatted and grouped properly for a receipt (theres much more than just 4 inputs).

When I loop through `$_POST` (using `foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)`), I have a conditional that checks if the value is an array, that is working just fine. When the value is not an array, the values get printed to the receipt. If it is an array, that array should be looped through independently to add in those inputs to the receipt together.

However, when I get to the array values, I am using a check to make sure at least one of the values is set (some of the values are automatically set, and I don't want to add the groups that only have the automatically set inputs).

When I echo out `$value` in the conditional where `$value` is an array, I get the "array to string conversion" notice, and it echoes out the word "array". Just as expected. But when I try to use `$value` as an array, i.e `$value["FirstName"]`, I get an illegal string offset error. I believe this means I am treating a string as an array?

So I am now echoing out the value before the conditional, and added a check in the conditional, `if(is_array($value)`.........
The echo prints out "array", showing me that the value is in fact an array. However, the conditional never runs anymore, telling me that the $value is NOT an array. Anyone know why this is happening? I have this code:

```
echo $value;
if (is_array($value) and $value['FirstName'] !== ""){
```

that gives the output:

> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in .../test2.php on line 90
>   Notice: Array to string conversion in .../test2.php on line 89
>   Array

(line 89 is the `echo $value` line; line 90 is the conditional)

Also, I know that the 'FirstName' element is in ALL the arrays that get submitted with the POST, so it can't be an invalid indexing problem. And I am submitting FirstNames, so they are not empty. So the conditional should run every time (it was running until I added the `is_array` check).

Comment: Instead of `echo $value` try a `var_dump($value)` which will show you the structure of the array/data. Also, don't assume that `FirstName` is always set just because you put it in the form. It is trivial to modify the form using the developer tools to add/remove form elements.

Comment: please show the code before these two lines.

Comment: In the code you pasted at the end, you used the word 'and' not the conditional and operator `&&`. 

The second notice about like 89, is due to echoing the array. To print an array like that, do `print_r($value, true)` or more easily `var_dump($value)`

I believe the 'illegal string offset error' is from calling `$value['FirstName']` when that array key is unset. To fix that, simply do `if(is_array($value) && isset($value['FirstName']) && $value['FirstName'] !== '') { //statement body here }` should work out for you. That is, providing I understood what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes to your code

```
if(is_array($value) && $value['FirstName']!='')
{
    echo $value['FirstName'];
}
```